# PHPLIST - Error sending messages when safe mode = Off

Tags: sendmail, safe-mode, phplist

I'm running `phplist-3.0.2` in a dedicate server with sendmail and when I try to switch php `safe_mode` to "Off" or "0" I get this error while I send a campaign:

```
Error sending message X (X/XXXX) to user@domain.com (user@domain.com).
```

The queue is trying to process but the error is always the same.

With `safe_mode ON` I don't get this error, but, of course I get the `<<safe_mode>>` warning.

Did somebody fix this? I don't want to start sending campaigns with `safe_mode ON`.

Answer (score 1):

Finally found the solution. The sendmail function was using qmail in our server.

After install and configuring postfix to replace qmail, PHPLIST is working fine with no errors.

The speed of sent increased x10 too.